# Openlayers 2 How to know the map is after panning/zooming

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

Firstly i found a logic to customize or extends Openlayers 2 Control Navigation. I dont want to custom the openlayers default, because I'm currently using 2 different map in one page. especially to custom after panning or zooming.

The purpose is I Whenever user after panning/zooming/wheel-zoom or the position/zoom of first map is change, it can get latests 4 LatLon of corner side from frame viewed first map then call a function to process it.

edit:
already found a way using event register

Comment: Can you clarify your second paragraph?

Comment: the second is after user panning the first map, it can give alert about LatLon of frame first map. frame first map means, the visible map on user view.

Answer (score 1):

Okey, maybe I found a better way using map.event.register

```
map.events.register("zoomend", map, function(e){    
    // after zoom
});

map.events.register('moveend', map, function (e) {
    // after pan
});
```

then to find corner latlon after it, I can use Map function

```
map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(new OpenLayers.Pixel(0,0)); // corner bot-lef
map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(new OpenLayers.Pixel(0,map.size.h)); // corner bot-right
map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(new OpenLayers.Pixel(map.size.w, map.size.h)); // corner top-right
map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(new OpenLayers.Pixel(map.size.w,0)); // corner top-left
```